# Adding a symbol for significance in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

R version 4.2.2 (2022-10-31 ucrt)
Packages: ggplot2, dplyr

I have a dataset that contains calculated numbers for water velocity within a stream. These include the mean, 5th quantile, 25th quantile, 75th quantile, 90th quantile, and if the results were significant (yes/no).

```
structure(list(Treatment = c("Discharge", "Discharge", "Discharge", 
"Discharge", "Discharge", "Discharge"), Species = c("Desert Sucker", 
"Desert Sucker", "Black Bass", "Black Bass", "Available", "Available"
), Stream = c("Wet Beaver", "Wet Beaver", "Wet Beaver", "Wet Beaver", 
"Wet Beaver", "Wet Beaver"), Group = c("High", "Low", "High", 
"Low", "High", "Low"), Mesohabitat = c("Riffle", "Riffle", "Riffle", 
"Riffle", "Riffle", "Riffle"), Velocity_Mean = c(0.574, 0.224, 
0.17, 0.143, 0.39, 0.185), Velocity_25 = c(0.148, 0.096, 0.054, 
0.039, 0.147, 0.032), Velocity_75 = c(0.846, 0.263, 0.244, 0.216, 
0.561, 0.291), Velocity_5 = c(0.034, 0.027, 0.029, 0.008, 0.004, 
0), Velocity_95 = c(1.468, 0.626, 0.372, 0.382, 1.104, 0.56), 
    V_Significance = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L)), row.names = c(1L, 
13L, 7L, 19L, 25L, 31L), class = "data.frame")
```

I've created a boxplot with ggplot2 using the following code

```
Velocity_Plot <- ggplot(data = Velocity, mapping = aes(y = Species, fill = Group))+
  scale_fill_manual("Group", values = c("grey70", "grey92"))+
  theme_bw()+
  labs(x = "Velocity (m/s)",
       y = "",
       title = "Discharge")+
  geom_boxplot(stat = "identity",
               mapping = aes(xmin = Velocity_5,
                             xlower = Velocity_25,
                             xmiddle = Velocity_Mean,
                             xupper = Velocity_75,
                             xmax = Velocity_95))+
  facet_grid(Mesohabitat ~Stream)
```

[Image of boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDq6f.png)

I'd like to add an asterisk or some other symbol to represent statistical significance that has been precaluculated but I can't figure out how to do so.

I've tried using stat_summary to add a point, but couldn't figure out how to tie the function back to the significance column. I've also looked at the ggsignif package but this seems to be more for if you need to calculate significance when I just need to symbolize significance.

I've tried

```
SigVD <- Velocity %>%
  filter(V_Significance == 1)

geom_text(data=SigVD, aes(y=Species),label="*",size=5,nudge_y=1, show.legend = FALSE)
```

But I receive an error because I do not have an X within aes

```
Error in `geom_text()`:
! Problem while setting up geom.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `compute_geom_1()`:
! `geom_text()` requires the following missing aesthetics: x
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

I'd like to achieve something similar to this:
[example of symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vBxF.png)

Comment: Provide a replicable data for velocity so that we can help you.

Comment: How are you defining "statistical significance"? A boxplot in general suggests data are "significantly different" by identifying them as outliers and optionally plotting those points (you have them here), I'm not sure what other statistical test may be expected here.

Comment: Welcome to SO, user22797688! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (you have a good start here!), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: @r2evans Thanks! I've added sample data and updated attempted code and the associated error. This data was produced through resampling so statistical significance was determined by a proportional mean of 10k p-values per row

Comment: We can't really use data from `str(.)` output, please use `dput` or programmatic with `data.frame`.

Comment: @r2evans My apologies, I've updated the relevant data and code. Thank you for the references and help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone looking for a solution to a similar problem in the future, here is how I was able to add a symbol to the plot.

```
#Setting x as 1.0 (because that will be easy to see)
VP_2 <- Velocity_Plot +
        geom_text(data = Velocity %>% 
        filter(V_Significance == 1), mapping = aes(y = Species, x = 1.0),
               label = "*")
                
VP_2
    
#Tying the location to the end of the upper whisker
VP_3 <- Velocity_Plot +
        geom_text(data = Velocity %>% 
        filter(V_Significance == 1), mapping=aes(y = Species, x = Velocity_95),
               label = "*")
VP_3
```

Solution credit: Jeff Oliver